# JAVA How to do PUT request REST Client

Tags: java, json, rest, client, put

Im doing a REST server and client using java to learn.
Everything works ok but the PUT request from the client dont pass the data in the body correctly because when I see the log in the server the parameters are NULL

This is the client PUT request code:

```
private static class Mod {
        int idUser;
        String nameUser;
        String passwordUser;

        public Mod(int idUser, String nameUser, String passwordUser) {
            this.idUser = idUser;
            this.nameUser = nameUser;
            this.passwordUser = passwordUser;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/users/" + idUser + "/");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<>();
                postDataParams.put("nameUser", this.nameUser);
                postDataParams.put("passwordUser", this.passwordUser);

                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                writer.write(getPutDataString(postDataParams));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                if (connection.getResponseCode() == 201) {
                    System.out.println("Modified");
                    connection.disconnect();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private String getPutDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    result.append("&");
                }
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the POST request. It uses the same way of "injecting" the parameters and works perfect:

```
private static class Create {
        String nameUser, passwordUser;

        public Create(String nameUser, String passwordUser) {
            this.nameUser = nameUser;
            this.passwordUser = passwordUser;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/users/");
                HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<>();
                postDataParams.put("nameUser", this.nameUser);
                postDataParams.put("passwordUser", this.passwordUser);

                myConnection.setDoInput(true);
                myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = myConnection.getOutputStream();

                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                myConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 201) {
                    System.out.println("Created");
                    myConnection.disconnect();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    result.append("&");
                }
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

The REST Controller in the server:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> index() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User show(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return this.userService.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public User create(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        this.userService.save(user);
        return user;
    }

    @PutMapping("/users/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public User update(@ModelAttribute User user, @PathVariable Long id) {
        User currentUser = this.userService.findById(id);
        currentUser.setNameUser(user.getNameUser());
        currentUser.setPasswordUser(user.getPasswordUser());
        this.userService.save(currentUser);
        return currentUser;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        this.userService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `x-www-form-urlencoded` because you are not sending any file.
Moreover, you need more work to manually do a `form-data` request so it's better to change the server so that it accepts `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters.

After you have modified the server, add the content type to the request:

```java
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

and remove this line:

```java
connection.setDoInput(true)
```

because you use the `HttpURLConnection` as output.

Note that you can make the PUT request easily with [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/).

Comment: Thanks for your time @Demetrio. If tried that and I still get the same error. I've updated the post with my Rest Controller in the server. I don't know where is the problem. In the POST im doing it the same way and it works perfect with form-data, ¿Why I have to change the PUT?

Comment: Maybe Spring doesn't support @ModelAttribute with PUT mapping. Try to send the parameters as JSON or declare each parameter in the method with the '@RequestParam("<paramName>")' annotation

Comment: If Spring doesn't support ModelAttribute with PUT mapping how can it be working correctly when testing with Postman? Shouln't it fail too?
How can I sent the parameter as a JSON? Do you know any guide or example? thank @Demetrio

Comment: @Fortun you probably didn't set the `Content-Type` in the `HttpURLConnection`. I tested your code and, without the `Content-Type`, it doesn't work